# "Voltage divider holds 37% of supply voltage at negative" wrong in textbook

Tags: voltage-divider, timer, comparator

In my textbook, it states that "the voltage divider of R3:R4 holds 37% of the supply voltage at negative".

However, I think it should be 63%.

[image]

Comment: I think you are wrong.  Can you edit the answer and go into more details on how you calculated your 63%?

Comment: negative what? ... the statement talks about the input, yet you left that out ... it is `37% of the supply voltage at negative input`   .... it is like saying `i bought a yellow`

Answer (score 5):

It is right in the textbook. The voltage divider applies 37% of the power supply voltage on the inverting input of the Op-amp.

Your confusion maybe because this input is 63% of the supply voltage full scale below its positive terminal. Which is equivalent to 37% above 0.

[image]